# Someone who does "mundane or repetitive work" for you?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Trying to come up with the name for a new product I am working on. This tool will help hiring managers with their repetitive or mundane work.
Something related to hiring or recruitment could also work as well.

First word came to my mind was "assistance". But it has a very broad meaning and doesn't fit well with hiring/recruitment.

Comment: Janitor?  Handyman?  Secretary?  Gopher?

Comment: Obviously, you looked at all of the synonyms and found nothing (?). Nor did I. Try "head hunter"?

Comment: First thing that came to my mind was "grunt" or "grunt work". Can't think of a snappy product name with that though it could be used in a strap line. "Takes the grunt work out of recruiting"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Dogsbody**.  [Definition](http://a%20person%20who%20is%20given%20boring,%20menial%20tasks%20to%20do.):

> a person who is given boring, menial tasks to do.

From [*Nineteen to the Dozen: Monologues and Bits and Bobs of Other Things*](http://Nineteen%20to%20the%20Dozen:%20Monologues%20and%20Bits%20and%20Bobs%20of%20Other%20Things%20%20By%20Sholem%20Aleichem,%20Ted%20Gorelick,%20Ken%20Frieden) by Sholem Aleichem, Ted Gorelick, and Ken Frieden

Call me **dogsbody**, call me menial, call me lackey, call me horse and I'll ride it to the jakes....

Comment: Thanks for your prompt. They all have a negative image associated with them. Specially if you compare them with "associate".

Comment: It might be worth saying that 'dogsbody' is used in the UK, whereas 'gopher' (suggested by Hot Licks) is used in North America.

Answer (score 3):

#### Automaton

["a person who acts in a mechanical or machinelike way"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automaton)

> Gloria worked like an ***automaton*** in the factory. The boredom dulled her spirit, and her hands became sore from peeling shrimp all day.

#### Minion

["someone who is not powerful or important and who obeys the orders of a powerful leader or boss"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minion)

> It didn't matter to Eugene that recounting all the items in the stock room a fourth time would be pointless waste of time, he simply assigned the task to one of his ***minions***.

Comment: I think he's asking for a word he could use in a professional setting. 'Minion' might be a bit comical for the scenario :P

Comment: @JonyAgarwal That word has been around much longer than the movie you're probably associating it with. There's nothing comical about its actual definition:  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minion

Comment: Oh, so you had the reference? My apologies. I think you should add the link, it would improve your answer and is a site policy too. I will upvote it once you add the link :)

Comment: Great. Just realized I had already upvoted it before you added the link.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal  Thank you for the suggestion! I added definitions for both words, linked to dictionary references.

Answer (score 2):

**Grunt.**
From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grunt):
Simple definition: "a person who does ordinary and boring work."
Definition 4b: "one who does routine unglamorous work —often used attributively (*grunt work*)"

Answer (score 1):

**[Drudge](http://tfd.com/drudge)**:

> A person who does tedious, menial, or unpleasant work.

**[Workhorse](http://tfd.com/workhorse)**:

> *Informal* A person who works tirelessly, especially at difficult or time-consuming tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**[Peon](http://tfd.com/peon)**

> A person who does menial or repetitive tasks and has a low rank in an organization or society.

**[Factotum](http://tfd.com/factotum)**

> An employee or assistant who serves in a wide range of capacities.

Answer (score -4):

More closely related to the original post,I may be inventing, but Human Resources Facilitator would be perfect for the military. "He's our new HRF".

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question at hand. They are not asking for the name of the role of a person.